# Using variable (which is an IP address) for key to an associative array gives errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, associative-array

This is my function where I'm reading a file, splitting each line by space and creating an array. I want to use 1st and 2nd element from the array as key and value to an associative array. The 1st element is an ip address.

```
function testRead {
  NEWHOST_IPS_OUT=<my_file>
  declare -a HOSTS_IP_ARR
  while read line
  do
      if [[ -z "$line" ]] || [[ "$line" =~ "#" ]]; then
              continue
      fi

      STR_ARRAY=($line)
      HOST_IP=${STR_ARRAY[1]}
      HOST_AZ=${STR_ARRAY[2]}

      HOSTS_IP_ARR["$HOST_IP"]="${HOST_AZ}"
      HOSTS_IP_ARR[hello]=2

  done < "$NEWHOST_IPS_OUT"
}
```

Issues & Findings:

```
* declare -A doesn't work, using `GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
```

./test.sh: line 4: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

```
* I tested with constant values using '-a' for an associative array. It worked

* On running this script I get the following error:
```

./test.sh: line 14: 127.0.0.1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0.0.1")

```
 This is line 14: HOSTS_IP_ARR["$HOST_IP"]="${HOST_AZ}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare -A doesn't work, using `GNU bash, version **3.2.25(1)-release** (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
```

There's your problem.  Associative arrays were only introduced into bash in version 4.

Answer (score 1):

`declare -a` creates a regular, non-associative array.

It could appear to be associative:

```
declare -a arr
arr["somekey"]=42
echo "${arr["somekey"]}"  # gives 42
```

but

```
arr["someotherkey"]=1000
echo "${arr["somekey"]}"  # now gives 1000
```

This is because `"somekey"` and `"someotherkey"` are interpretted as arithmetic expressions. Bash tries to look them up as variable names, find them unset, and therefore consider the value to be `0`.

`127.0.0.1` is an invalid arithmetic expression, and that's why you get that error.

Comment: So what's the best way to solve this problem? The code snippet you see reads a file with ips and their corresponding regions. I need to establish the association b/w the IP addresses such that 1 IP can be only if 1 region. Do I define 2 arrays and use the same index for both? Is there a better way to do it? In the end I want to use each IP and it's corresponding region to do some processing.

Comment: @user1071840 use Bash4 or awk